# Why the spring boot vaadin app can not run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I just created a custom app via [this.](https://vaadin.com/start/latest/project-base)
I wanted to create a spring boot app with Vaadin. But when I ran as a spring boot project I got this error. What is the reason I'm getting this error in a an empty project? I don't think there's a problem with Maven. This is the first time I've tried your promise.

Thanks for the help.

Here is the error log:

```
                          _  _                      _             _   
__   __  __ _   __ _   __| |(_) _ __           ___ | |__    __ _ | |_ 
\ \ / / / _` | / _` | / _` || || '_ \  _____  / __|| '_ \  / _` || __|
 \ V / | (_| || (_| || (_| || || | | ||_____|| (__ | | | || (_| || |_ 
  \_/   \__,_| \__,_| \__,_||_||_| |_|        \___||_| |_| \__,_| \__|


2019-09-17 15:30:30.181  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] com.vaad.chat.spring.Application         : Starting Application on meren-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC with PID 22568 (started by meren in /home/meren/Masaüstü/vaadin-chat)
2019-09-17 15:30:30.184  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] com.vaad.chat.spring.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-17 15:30:30.231  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-09-17 15:30:30.231  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-09-17 15:30:31.158  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-17 15:30:31.181  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-17 15:30:31.182  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-09-17 15:30:31.263  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-17 15:30:31.263  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1031 ms
2019-09-17 15:30:31.667 ERROR 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent resource of [/home/meren/Masaüstü/vaadin-chat/target/classes/com/vaad/chat/spring/Application.class] not found in the resources!
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CustomResourceLoader.collectResources(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:670) ~[vaadin-spring-12.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CustomResourceLoader.getResources(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:640) ~[vaadin-spring-12.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4747) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4755) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:316) ~[vaadin-spring-12.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4680) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:456) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:416) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.vaad.chat.spring.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]

2019-09-17 15:30:31.673 ERROR 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2019-09-17 15:30:31.674 ERROR 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2019-09-17 15:30:31.710  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-17 15:30:31.716  WARN 22568 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-09-17 15:30:31.726  INFO 22568 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-17 15:30:31.733 ERROR 22568 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.vaad.chat.spring.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:416) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:108) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It misses the parent class of `com/vaad/chat/spring/Application.class` how did you start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE*

`mvn clean install` in pom file will solve the problem and you don't have to delete this line. Anyway if you delete it, you won't use vaadin.

*OLD ANSWER*

I had same problem. I generated a project by the help of vaadin.com/start and I got this error log. However I don't see your pom file but I think it's similar to mine.
If it is true, try to remove this line from vaadin dependency: `<version>14.0.4</version>`

**Here is pom from [vaadin.com/start](https://vaadin.com/start/latest):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    vaadin-spring-boot-starter
                </artifactId>
    <!--            <version>14.0.4</version>-->
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <!-- declare the latest Vaadin version
                         as a property or directly here -->
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>14.0.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

---

Or you generate it by the help of Spring Boot Initalizr, remove `<vaadin.version>14.0.5</vaadin.version>` line from properties tags

**This is pom from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!--        <vaadin.version>14.0.5</vaadin.version>-->
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```